# Logging with role in Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm new in Node.js and Express and I have a problem with access control with Passport.
I want to check with which role user is logged in.
My user schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password:{
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  username:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role:{
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  activated:{
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My passport.js file

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (passport) => {
  //Local Strategy
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
      //Match email
      let query = {email: email}
      User.findOne(query, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        if(!user) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
        }

        //Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
           if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
          }
        });
      });
  }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
}
```

The small part of app.js file where I'm setting up global variable user

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});
```

Part of layout.pug file where I'm using global user variable

```
.navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav
        li
          a(href='/') Home
        if user
          li
            a(href='/articles/add') Add article
```

What I want to do is to check if user has an admin role. I tried to do that in different ways but with no success. I wanted to check the role in app.js, but I was getting errors:

```
if(req.user.role == 'admin'){
    res.locals.admin = req.user;
}
```

Also I wanted to pass only the role in passport.js and it was working then but I need also other property of user.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
});
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `req.isAuthenticated()` then checking the role. Cuz if req.user is null then you can't check the property 'admin' of null

```
if(req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.role == 'admin'){
  res.locals.admin = req.user;
}
```

The req.isAuthenticated() function is provided by passport.js

Comment: I was trying doing sth like that, but I got then this error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
    at app.get (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\nauka\ArticlesKnowledgeBase\app.js:77:33)`

Comment: I just edited my answer. Sorry that I forgot '&&' in if statement and function isAuthenticated()

Comment: You can look at my project to see example
https://gitlab.com/yyyyaaa/group-profile/blob/master/server/routes.js